# Generate DSA Keys for OpenSSH in Golang

Tags: go, ssh, cryptography, openssh, dsa

I read through a few examples to generate DSA keys for OpenSSH in Go. And my clean code snippet and outputs are listed below.

It has two problems:

1. for 2048-bit length, the public key can't be loaded via `ssh.ParseAuthorizedKey`, for error: "ssh: no key found".
2. OpenSSH client and GitHub SSH can't accept it.

Code snippets:

```golang
// GenerateDSAKeys generates DSA public and private key pair with given size for SSH.
func GenerateDSAKeys(bitSize int, passphrase string) (pubKey string, privKey string, err error) {
    params := new(dsa.Parameters)

    // see http://golang.org/pkg/crypto/dsa/#ParameterSizes
    if err = dsa.GenerateParameters(params, rand.Reader, dsaSizeFromLength(bitSize)); err != nil {
        return
    }

    var privateKey dsa.PrivateKey
    privateKey.PublicKey.Parameters = *params

    // this generates a public & private key pair
    if err = dsa.GenerateKey(&privateKey, rand.Reader); err != nil {
        return
    }

    // generate public key
    var publicKey ssh.PublicKey
    if publicKey, err = ssh.NewPublicKey(&privateKey.PublicKey); err != nil {
        return
    }

    // encode public key
    pubBytes := ssh.MarshalAuthorizedKey(publicKey)

    // encode private key
    var (
        bytes     []byte
        privBytes []byte
    )
    if bytes, err = asn1.Marshal(privateKey); err != nil {
        return
    }
    privBytes, err = encodePEMBlock(&pem.Block{
        Type:  "DSA PRIVATE KEY",
        Bytes: bytes,
    }, passphrase)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    return string(pubBytes), string(privBytes), nil
}

func dsaSizeFromLength(l int) dsa.ParameterSizes {
    switch l {
    case 1024:
        return dsa.L1024N160
    case 2048:
        return dsa.L2048N224
    case 3072:
        return dsa.L3072N256
    default:
        return dsa.L2048N256
    }
}
```

Output for 1024:

```sh
bash-3.2$ cat id_dsa.pub
ssh-dss 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 vej@Vej-Work-MBP.local
bash-3.2$ cat id_dsa
-----BEGIN DSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END DSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

For 2048, output:

```sh
bash-3.2$ cat id_dsa.pub
ssh-dss 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 vej@Vej-Work-MBP.local
bash-3.2$ cat id_dsa
-----BEGIN DSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END DSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Can you please tell me how resolve it, and make it works?

Comment: Any reason why you cannot go with RSA keys? Most cryptosystems have switched to RSA for larger key lengths. Possibly they don't support the 2048 bit (and higher) domain parameters.

Answer (score 2):

OpenSSH stopped supporting DSA (aka ssh-dss) by default over 5 years ago; see
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/112802/why-openssh-deprecated-dsa-keys
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/146379/does-ssh-support-dsa-with-2048-bit-keys
https://superuser.com/questions/1016989/ssh-dsa-keys-no-longer-work-
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247612/ssh-keeps-skipping-my-pubkey-
You can reenable it on your client following instructions on Qs like those or the openssh website or documentation, but [github won't accept it](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/checking-for-existing-ssh-keys) so you can't make that work. (You could set up your own server, and use it there.)

I don't know why some go code (library?) doesn't accept the 2048-bit publickey -- if you give a reference I could try to loook -- but (both) your *privatekey* files are incorrect, I'm guessing due to the structuring used in `crypto/dsa` shown at your link. The key is being marshalled (serialized) to ASN.1 as nested sequences, namely SEQUENCE { pub = SEQUENCE { params = SEQUENCE {p,q,g}, y }, x } which conceptually is a reasonable structure, but the PEM (or pseudo-PEM) type `DSA PRIVATE KEY` is de-facto defined by SSLeay-now-OpenSSL as using a single level: SEQUENCE { p,q,g, y, x } .